# nrf24l01+ Arduino code doesn't seem to be transmitting/receiving data

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port

I've confirmed that both nrf24l01 modules work as well as both nanos. Ive also tried it with a simple code and got it working. I've tried everything i can think and am now stuck on what to try.

could someone maybe check if this code works with their nrf24l01 module or something?

Receiving code:

```
#include "SPI.h"
#include "RF24.h"
#include "nRF24L01.h"

#define CE_PIN 9
#define CSN_PIN 10

#define INTERVAL_MS_SIGNAL_LOST 1000
#define INTERVAL_MS_SIGNAL_RETRY 250

RF24 radio(CE_PIN, CSN_PIN);

const byte address[6] = "00001";

//NRF24L01 buffer limit is 32 bytes (max struct size)
struct payload {
  byte data1;
  char data2;

  //byte pot_value;
};

payload payload;

unsigned long lastSignalMillis = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  radio.begin();

  //Append ACK packet from the receiving radio back to the transmitting radio
  radio.setAutoAck(false); //(true|false)
  //Set the transmission datarate
  radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS); //(RF24_250KBPS|RF24_1MBPS|RF24_2MBPS)

  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_HIGH); //(RF24_PA_MIN|RF24_PA_LOW|RF24_PA_HIGH|RF24_PA_MAX)
  //Default value is the maximum 32 bytes
  radio.setPayloadSize(sizeof(payload));

  radio.openReadingPipe(0, address);
  radio.startListening();
}

void loop()
{
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (radio.available()) {
    radio.read(&payload, sizeof(payload));

    Serial.println("Received");

    Serial.print("Data1:");
    Serial.println(payload.data1);

    Serial.print("Data2:");
    Serial.println(payload.data2);

    //Serial.print("Data3:");
    //Serial.println(payload.pot_value);

    lastSignalMillis = currentMillis;
  }

  if (currentMillis - lastSignalMillis > INTERVAL_MS_SIGNAL_LOST) {
    lostConnection();
  }
  delay(INTERVAL_MS_SIGNAL_RETRY);
}

void lostConnection()
{
  Serial.println("We have lost connection, preventing unwanted behavior");
}
```

Transmitting code:

```
#include "SPI.h"
#include "RF24.h"
//#include <printf.h>`--

#define CE_PIN 9
#define CSN_PIN 10

//#define POT_PIN

#define INTERVAL_MS_TRANSMISSION 250

RF24 radio(CE_PIN, CSN_PIN);

const byte address[6] = "00001";

//NRF24L01 buffer limit is 32 bytes (max struct size)
struct payload {
  byte data1;
  char data2;
  //byte pot_value;
};

payload payload;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  if (radio.isChipConnected()) {
    radio.begin();
    Serial.println("nRF24L01 Intialiazed!");
    
    //Append ACK packet from the receiving radio back to the transmitting radio
    radio.setAutoAck(false); //(true|false)

    //Set the transmission datarate
    radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS); //(RF24_250KBPS|RF24_1MBPS|RF24_2MBPS)

    radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_HIGH); //(RF24_PA_MIN|RF24_PA_LOW|RF24_PA_HIGH|RF24_PA_MAX)

    //Default value is the maximum 32 bytes
    radio.setPayloadSize(sizeof(payload));

    radio.openWritingPipe(address);
    radio.stopListening();
  }else{
    Serial.println("No connection between nRF24L01 and Arduino! ");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  payload.data1 = 123;
  payload.data2 = 'x';

  //payload.pot_value = analogRead(POT_PIN);

  if(radio.write(&payload, sizeof(payload))) {
    Serial.print("Data1:");
    Serial.println(payload.data1);

    Serial.print("Data2:");
    Serial.println(payload.data2);

    //Serial.print("Data3:");
    //Serial.println(payload.pot_value);

    Serial.println("Sent");

  }else {
    Serial.println("Error! Payload not sent");
  }

  delay(INTERVAL_MS_TRANSMISSION);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`RF24::openReadingPipe()` and `RF24::openWritingPipe()` expect address as `uint64_t`. In both your programs `address` is an array of bytes which decays to a pointer when passed to a function. So open*Pipe() functions get different pointer values instead of numberic address `1`. Obviously it's very unlikely pointer values to be the same in different programs.
If you enable compiler warnings, you'd see

> invalid conversion from 'const byte* {aka const unsigned char*}' to 'uint64_t {aka long long unsigned int}'